# understanding an eventListener solution from Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Help would be really appreciated, I’ve been trying to figure this out for hours now.

So this was the solution to an exercise I was doing:

```
<!doctype html>
<tab-panel>
<div data-tabname="one">Tab one</div>
<div data-tabname="two">Tab two</div>
<div data-tabname="three">Tab three</div>
</tab-panel>
<script>
function asTabs(node) {
let tabs = Array.from(node.children).map(node => {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = node.getAttribute("data-tabname");
  let tab = {node, button};
  button.addEventListener("click", () => selectTab(tab));
  return tab;
});
let tabList = document.createElement("div");
for (let {button} of tabs) tabList.appendChild(button);
node.insertBefore(tabList, node.firstChild);

function selectTab(selectedTab) {
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    let selected = tab == selectedTab;
    console.log(selected)
    tab.node.style.display = selected ? "" : "none";
    tab.button.style.color = selected ? "red" : "";
  }
}
selectTab(tabs[0]);
}
asTabs(document.querySelector("tab-panel"));
</script>
```

the part that confused me is on line 13:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => selectTab(tab));
```

Normally when adding event listeners, you wouldnt need to place a function call inside another function - it would be sufficient to say something like this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", selectTab(tab));
```

However when I do, an error comes up saying:

```
ReferenceError: tabs is not defined (line 15 in function selectTab)
called from line 7 in function Array.from.map.node
called from line 3 in function asTabs
called from line 25
```

and that’s where I’m lost.
Thanks for your time as always

Answer (score 2):

> Normally when adding event listeners, you wouldnt need to place a
>   function call inside another function - it would be sufficient to say
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> button.addEventListener("click", selectTab(tab));
> ```

That isn't true.

The second argument to `addEventListener` needs to be a function. That function will be called when the event happens.

`selectTab(tab)` calls the `selectTab` function **immediately** (passing it the value of the `tab` variable). You can only do that if that function's return value it another function.

---

> However when I do, an error comes up saying:
>
> ReferenceError: tabs is not defined (line 15 in function selectTab)

`tabs` is defined then the `Array.from` call finished evaluating. The event listener is added as part of the evaluation of that. i.e. before the value has been assigned to `tabs`.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "You can only do that if that function's return value it another function."

Comment: If the return value of `selectTab()` is, for example, `3`, then it would be a number, not a function, and you can't use a number as an event listener. You can only use a function.